# Finding Green's function of $k(x) T''(x) + k'(x)T'(x) = -Q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I want to find Green's function for differential equation of $T(x)$

$$
k(x) T''(x) + k'(x)T'(x) = -Q(x)
$$

Any hints for getting started on this?

Comment: The Green's function for the problem of solving for $T$ at fixed $k$ or for the problem of solving for $k$ at fixed $T$?

Comment: @Ian Solving for $T$

Comment: Well, the problem is first order linear in $T'$, so if you look at $S'+\frac{k'}{k} S = \delta$ then you can solve for $S$ by the method of integrating factors, then integrate the result. Keep the zero initial data in place and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot!